# nginx and php-fpm 502 error

Tags: php, nginx

I looked for many solutions for that issue. However, none of them helped me to solve it. The error that shown in /var/log/nginx/error.log as follows:

```
2017/04/21 16:08:16 [error] 29233#0: *319 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "..."
```

Nginx config as follows:

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name ... ...;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/....cer;
    #ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/....cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/....key;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 

    root /var/www/drupal7; ## <-- Your only path reference.

    # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg module
    # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
    gzip_static on;
    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 2048M;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
            return 403;
    }

    # No no for private
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
            return 403;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
            return 403;
    }
    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location /adore-djatoka {
#            if($args ~* "/adore-djatoka/resolver?url_ver=.+&rft_id=.+&svc_id=.+") {
#                rewrite ^ http://...:8080/adore-djatoka/resolver?url_ver=$0&rft_id=$2&svc_id=$1 last;
#            }
#            rewrite    ^(.*)https(.*)$    $1http$2;
             proxy_pass http://...:8080/adore-djatoka;
#            proxy_redirect http://...:8080/adore-djatoka /adore-djatoka;
            #proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            # You have 2 options here
            # For D7 and above:
            # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
            rewrite ^ /index.php;
            # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # For Munin
    location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            #fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # This is for D7 and D8
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

If it'll be required I can post php-fpm config file, also.

Thanks,

Can

Comment: Please include your nginx config

Comment: @NullDev nginx config included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing `fastcgi_read_timeout` parameter to `600` helped me to solve my problem. Now, it's a little bit slow on loading the site. However I can preview and manage the site, at least. Thanks for your replies @NullDev.

Answer (score 4):

Try to **replace** your PHP block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
}
```

By this, depending on your PHP Version,

For **PHP 5**:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Or for **PHP 7**:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

For **PHP 7.4**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

And so on and so forth. You can always check what `sock`'s are available in `/run/php/`:

```sh
ls -la /run/php
```

then just specify the version you want to use in your Nginx config.

Don't forget to restart/reload nginx after those config changes (as root):

```sh
# check for config errors
nginx -t

# make sure the command above doesn't yield any errors.
# Then reload nginx
service nginx reload
```

Comment: I'm using PHP 5 for the project. I did what you mentioned however nothing changed @NullDev. 


2017/04/22 13:16:46 [error] 29233#0: *29976 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "..."

Comment: Are you sure you applied the changes correctly? Your log still says `fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000` which is not present in the version I provided. Make sure you edit the correct config, remove the old php block as mentioned, insert the block for PHP5 and restart nginx (`service nginx restart`)

Comment: I did what you said in nginx conf. That line you mentioned comes from php conf. I'm sure about that from my previous trys.

Comment: for PHP 7.4:
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;